# Pandas: calculate first purchase amount

Tags: python, pandas, select, pandas-groupby, calculated-columns

I need to calculate the first purchase amount for every client. This is my code:

**ticket.groupby(['user_reference_id','total_amount']).reference_date.min().reset_index()**``

And i have this result:

**user_reference_id   total_amount    reference_date***

```
    159                  12.77       2019-06-17

    159                  19.73       2019-06-17

    159                  21.55       2019-06-18

    159                  49.15       2019-06-16

    159                  49.66       2019-06-14
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPvHe.png)

I need it grouped by user_reference_id with the minimum reference_date (first date when a customer made the purchase) and corresponding total_amount.
In this case i need the next output: reference_date 2019-06-14, user_reference_id 159 and total_amount 49.66

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there input data as well? To format it correctly, use `Ctrl`+`K`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be:

**step 1:** sort by id and date

```
df=df.sort_values(['user_reference_id', 'reference_date'], ascending=True)
```

**Step 2:** as df is sorted, get the first value using groupby.agg function.

```
df_result=df.groupby('user_reference_id',as_index=False).agg({'reference_date':'first', 'total_amount':'first'})
```